# What this C++ code explains

Tags: c++

What is this expression saying, it seems like some constants, then it should return the same value right?

```
if (_has_bits_[8 / 32] & (0xffu << (8 % 32))) {......
```

Comment: What exactly do you need explaining? Do you understand what each symbol means? Do you understand how arrays and bitwise operators work? Did your introductory book not explain these?

Comment: The expression says to me "Look at me, I'm obfuscated!"

Comment: That's either deliberate obfuscation, or it's part of a larger block of code where using operations instead of constants makes a pattern apparent to an informed reader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That depends on the contents of the `_has_bits_` array. You can evaluate the rest of expression faily easy: `8 / 32` is `0` so you always use the value of `_has_bits_[0]`. `8%32` always evaluates to `8`, so you always get the total expression:

```
_has_bits_[0] & 0xff00u
```